# is "access-control-allow-origin" a secure way to restrict communication between two servers?

Tags: security, http, http-headers

I have two servers, A and B. I want server B to only accept HTTP requests from server A.
is "access-control-allow-origin" a secure way to implement that?

Answer (score 6):

No.

[HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is sent from server to client, or client to server. It's fine for protecting a cooperating client against attacks on the client, but it's ***not*** fine for protecting the server against anything. Any client is free to ignore it if it so desires; there's nothing the server can do to enforce it.

Implement real authentication, such as TLS client certificates, bearer tokens or a similar scheme.